# How do I setup a cloud server to share and sync files on ESXi hosted environment?

Tags: sync, cloud, cloud-computing, owncloud

I want to setup my private cloud network for my company for syncing and sharing files.  Instead of using existing players like dropbox, google drive, amazon etc. I want to setup my own cloud infrastructure.  The requirement is to easily share private data internally within the organization.  I already have an ESXi based cloud environment, running several virtual machines in it.  Will it be feasible and achievable?

Comment: "Cloud" is not *a* thing. Your question is the equivalent of "I want to do manufacturing. The requirement is for widgets which can be sold. I already have delivery trucks."

Comment: I need to setup a private cloud storage for syncing and sharing files within the organizaion, instead of using available alternatives.  I hope, it makes my point clear.

Comment: So what you want is called a **file server**. I'm not sure what you think ESX (a VM hypervisor) has to with that.

Comment: I have ESXi server hosting several virtual machines.  I want to add a new virtual machine towards sharing and syncing files.  We have our own setup in a hosted environment, and we don't want to use infrastructure from others, we want to set it on our own, using our own infrastructure, by implementing it on a virtual machine hosted in ESXi.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to store your data on your own servers instead of external servers, and use features like dropbox for synching.

I have researched this some 2-3 months ago myself and could find only one service that allows similar service levels as dropbox. The provider that I found was [Tonido](http://www.tonido.com/cloud/). You can manage your own userbase etc.

However they do not have 100% of the dropbox features, such as headless linux clients.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into a product called [**Accellion**](http://www.accellion.com/)

They have an application called KiteDrive that is pretty much drop box but for your own users. No one else can access it but who you give access to it. They can download the application and connect to your home network where ever they are. It just uses two VMs.

That gives you all the functionality described in the question.  It's what I use in my office.

You have to pay for it, but it's pretty darn neat.  All it needs is storage. It also has another appliance called Transfer, that will grab big files that are being sent from Exchange and push them to a file share so they can be retrieved from there.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of "How do I...", it just mentions a tool.  Please read http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers for guidance on recommending software.  Thanks.

Comment: This is a for-pay product. Isn't there a free alternative?

Comment: I fixed the link, put up the product with a description.